# chess board using javascript and dom

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a chessboard just like this.

[image]

I did create a table And don'r know how to colour it. A also need to print the board name (like A1, A2, ... H8) and be able to pust any figuere in any of the cell.

For start this is the code to create a table:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ChessBoard</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CreateTable(){
            var poz = document.getElementById('space');

            // createing table adn inserting into document
            tab = document.createElement('table');
            poz.appendChild(tab);

            tab.border = '5';

            for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                // creating row and inserting into document
                var row = tab.insertRow(i);

                for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                    // creating cells and fill with data (numbers)
                    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
                    cell.innerHTML = i*j;
                    cell.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                    cell.style.color = 'white';
                    cell.style.height = '50px';
                    cell.style.width = '50px';

                };
            };

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="CreateTable()" id ="space">

</body>
</html>
```

How do i fill specific cell with figure (like A3, E5, H8, ...)? Figure are imgages.

Part 2:
I did create a board with your help. 
Now I'm trying to do some more from this code.

1. How do I put several different images into several cells? I'm trying to get right working code, but with no success. This images should appear when the tabel will be loaded (when i press button CreateTable).
   I try to create with this code:
2. In this point I would like to put figures on board. When i create table it should be blank. Then there will be buttons to add figures. At the beginning for each different figure own button

something like this:

```
function addKing(idStr){
  cell =  document.getElementById(idStr);    
  if(cell != null){
  // works for color, doesn't work for images!!
  //  cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      cell.src = 'http://akramar.byethost8.com/images/SplProg/DN3/images/50px/king_m.png'
  }
}
```

Button addKing in html:

```
<button id="king" onclick="addKing(prompt('Insert field'))">Add King</button>
```

3. upgrading previousu code to even better if i can put all together and select which one I like to insert (promtpt window 1: what figure:'king, queen, ...', prompt window 2: on what position would you like to insert: 'A1, B3, ...')).

   function addImage (type, position){
     var img = ??
   }

When I pres button add image the prompt window should appear and ask for **type** (king, queen, root, ...) and **location** (A1, B4, ...) (for further update perhaps even color (black or white) but let build step by step).

All tis chessboard I would like to build just in javascript and with dom.

link to not working exaple: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPAZY/)

Comment: How about using a CSS background image?

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far? There are different ways that you can accomplish this.

Comment: You should store your cells in an array as you create them. The innerHTML line is odd; that will write `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7;0,2,4,...`. To write a letter, you can use a string "ABCDEFG" and `charAt`

Comment: to checkerboard, you can change `'blue'` to `((i+j)&1)?'blue':'white'` (checks if `i+j` is even or odd)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you need to support only modern browsers, the chess-board is *entirely* do-able with CSS using counters, and generated-content:

```
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}

td {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00f;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #999;
}

tbody {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
    counter-reset: cellNumber;
}

td {
    counter-increment: cellNumber;
}

td::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber, upper-alpha) counter(cellNumber, decimal);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TLEF8/1/).

The above tested in Chromium 24 and Firefox 19, both on Ubuntu 12.10.

And for a JavaScript approach:

```
var chess = {
    createBoard: function (dimension) {
        if (!dimension || isNaN(dimension) || !parseInt(dimension, 10)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            dimension = typeof dimension === 'string' ? parseInt(dimension, 10) : dimension;
            var table = document.createElement('table'),
                tbody = document.createElement('tbody'),
                row = document.createElement('tr'),
                cell = document.createElement('td'),
                rowClone,
                cellClone;
            table.appendChild(tbody);
            for (var r = 0; r < dimension; r++) {
                rowClone = row.cloneNode(true);
                tbody.appendChild(rowClone);
                for (var c = 0; c < dimension; c++) {
                    cellClone = cell.cloneNode(true);
                    rowClone.appendChild(cellClone);
                }
            }
            document.body.appendChild(table);
            chess.enumerateBoard(table);
        }
    },
    enumerateBoard : function (board) {
        var rows = board.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
            text = document.createTextNode(),
            rowCounter,
            len,
            cells;
        for (var r = 0, size = rows.length; r<size; r++){
            rowCounter = String.fromCharCode(65 + r);
            cells  = rows[r].getElementsByTagName('td');
            len = cells.length;
            rows[r].className = r%2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
            for (var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                cells[i].className = i%2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
                cells[i].appendChild(text.cloneNode());
                cells[i].firstChild.nodeValue = rowCounter + i;
            }
        }
    }
};

chess.createBoard(10);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TLEF8/4/).

Answer (score 2):

You can tie an ID to the cell, and then use that ID to reference and updated the background as needed.  Here is one example using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/7Z6hJ

```
function CreateTable(){
            var poz = document.getElementById('space');

            // createing table adn inserting into document
            tab = document.createElement('table');
            poz.appendChild(tab);

            tab.border = '5';

            for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                // creating row and inserting into document
                var row = tab.insertRow(i);

                for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                    // creating cells and fill with data (numbers)
                    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
                    var idStr = String.fromCharCode(97 + i).toUpperCase() + (j+1);
                    cell.innerHTML = idStr;
                    cell.id = idStr;
                    cell.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                    cell.style.color = 'white';
                    cell.style.height = '50px';
                    cell.style.width = '50px';

                };
            };

        }
function updateRow(idStr)
{
    cell =  document.getElementById(idStr);    
    if(cell != null)
    {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

As some have mentioned, there is probably a better way to go about this (using css and jQuery, etc) but this answer sticks with what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable inside the top loop to save the "letter" name of the row (eg. A, B, C).

```
// creating row and inserting into document
var row = tab.insertRow(i);
var row_letter = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
```

Then in the second loop combine the row name and column number.

```
cell.innerHTML = row_letter + j;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to do some math for correctly coloring and adding labels. Here is the part of code for doing magic:

```
             1       cell.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(65 + i) + (j + 1);
             2       if((i+j)%2){ cell.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; }
             3       else{ cell.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; }
             4       cell.style.color = 'black';
             5       cell.style.height = '50px';
             6       cell.style.width = '50px';
```

Let me explain. In first line, you take constant 65, which is ASCII code for letter 'A'. While you change the letter by rows, you add `i` counter to it, so you get 65+0, 65+1, ..., 65+7. Their ASCII equivalents (which you get with `String.fromCharCode()`) are A, B, ..., H. Now when you have that letter, easily add number of cell to it `(j + 1)`. You can remove '1' and leave just `j` and make inner loop go from 1 to 8.

Lines 2, 3: Colors are alternating - every second row have the same color. So, just test if is i+j dividable by 2.

For adding figure, you have to make some function that will do `cell.innerHTML = <SOME IMAGE>`. But, I guess, it's for second question.

Hope I helped you understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I case if someone is looking for a way to visualize a chessboard using JS (as I was doing and accidentally came to this question), here is an excellent [JS library](http://chessboardjs.com/) to do this.

It can create something like this

[image]

and much more in no time just by doing the following:

**JavaScript**

```
var ruyLopez = 'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R';
var board = new ChessBoard('board', ruyLopez);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
```